# Instances aren't aligning to normals in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, normals

I'm trying to make the instances I've created "lay" on top of the mesh, similar to snake scales. I have a simple geometry node setup. I've fiddled with my nodes but am still stuck.[image]

Comment: Not sure what kind of effect you're trying to achieve, do you know that you can pass a profile (has to be 2D! all $z = 0$) to a "Curve to Mesh" node? Oh and your instances **are** aligning to normals, it's just that you're misinterpreting what's happening on the screen.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender.SE! This question looks like a dulicate of.... (please use the search) ...or any other of the myriad of questions dealing with the *Align Euler to Vector* node?